# Ensure work was not done yesterday MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

This query currently selects people from a database that have done less than 8 hours of work in the last 2 weeks, that is working as I would like it to, I am now wondering how I go about filtering out employees that have worked on the previous day (consecutive work days not allowed)

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, SUM(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.started_at, 
s.ended_at))) as shift_hours
FROM employee e, shift s
WHERE e.id = s.employee_id
AND s.started_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW()
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING shift_hours < 8
AND shift_hours < 4 s.started_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
```

(Bottom line is where I have attempted to complete this, but the compiler does not like the syntax and won't tell me exactly where it has gone wrong)

Am I thinking on the right lines here?

Thanks!

EDIT: SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/717c3e

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN instead of archaic cross product syntax.

Comment: Add `AND e.id NOT IN (query that selects employees that worked yesterday)` to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! Would I delete the final line if I was to add that? And I am a little confused, I assume it would be something like

```WHERE e.id = s.employee_id AND e.id NOT IN s.started_at 
    BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();```